# Equivalence between $\neg\neg\bot$ and $\bot$ in intuitionistic logic.

Tags: logic, constructive-mathematics

As the title says, why are those two equivalent? I can find a simple derivation (using natural deduction) of $\bot$ from $\neg\neg\bot$, but i fail at proving the other implication.

Comment: Well, $\lnot \bot$ is $\bot \to \bot$, which is a tautology. So $\lnot \lnot \bot$ is also a contradiction.

Comment: I was looking for a proof using natural deduction, since I don't know semantic methods for intuitionistic logic...

Comment: What are you meaning by "natural deduction" - in propositional logic, there is a deduction of $(p \Rightarrow \neg \neg p)$, and $(\neg \neg p \Rightarrow p)$ is an axiom, so the equivalence does hold for all propositions (i.e. not just for false), but I can't think of a proof of this between "intuitively obvios" and the formal "finite list of statements that are either axioms or obtained (by modus ponens) from previous statements".

Comment: Well, $\neg\neg p \rightarrow p$ is an axiom in classical logic, it doesn't hold in intuitionistic logic. And natural deduction is a kind of proof calculus, like sequent calculus (kinda).

Comment: My argument can be made into a natural deduction proof. The point is to remind you that $\lnot \phi$ is an abbreviation of $(\phi \to \bot)$.

Comment: Well, ex. falso quodlibet (explosion) holds in intuitionistic logic, so there's no problem in deriving *anything* from $\bot$, including $\neg\neg\bot$

Comment: A very roundabout approach to this question is : if LEM holds for a proposition, then DNE holds for it.  And LEM holds for any decidable expression.  And $\bot$ is trivially decidable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) One of the rules of inference in standard natural deduction systems for intuitionistic logic is ex falso quodlibet, i.e.

> From $\bot$ infer $\varphi$ for any $\varphi$.

So, as a particular application, we have a one-step derivation of, in particular,  $\neg\neg\bot$ from $\bot$.

(b) As you say the other direction is also intuitionistically provable. Thus $\bot$ trivially entails $\bot$ so (by the intuitionistically acceptable version of reductio that if you can infer $\bot$ from $\psi$, then that gives you $\neg\psi$), $\neg\bot$ is a theorem. But then $\neg\neg\bot$ as an assumption, combined with this theorem (so a pair of the form $\neg\psi$, $\psi$) gives you $\bot$ (by the introduction rule for $\bot$).

Comment: The (b) was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The $\bot \to \neg\neg\bot$ implication is a special case of $\forall \alpha.\ \forall \beta.\ \alpha \to (\beta \to \alpha)$.
Below there are both derivations using [Curry-Howard isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence).

Formula 
$$((\bot \to \bot) \to \bot) \to \bot$$ 
is a special case of 
$$\forall \beta.\ \forall \alpha.\ ((\alpha \to \alpha) \to \beta) \to \beta $$
which can be proved by $\lambda$-term
$$\lambda f.\ f\ (\lambda x.\ x)$$

The other implication

$$\bot \to ((\bot \to \bot) \to \bot)$$

is a special case of

$$\forall \beta.\ \forall \alpha.\ \beta \to (\alpha \to \beta)$$

which can be proved by $\lambda$-term

$$\lambda x. \lambda f.\ x$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$